# Explain this pattern matching code

Tags: scala

This code is from *[Querying a Dataset with Scala's Pattern Matching](http://notes.langdale.com.au/Querying_a_Dataset_with_Scala_s_Pattern_Matching.html)*:

```
object & { def unapply[A](a: A) = Some((a, a)) }

"Julie" match {
  case Brothers(_) & Sisters(_) => "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)"
  case Siblings(_) => "Julie's siblings are all the same sex"
  case _ => "Julie has no siblings"
}

// => "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)"
```

How does `&` actually work? I don't see a Boolean test anywhere for the conjunction. How does this Scala magic work?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261358/pattern-matching-with-conjunctions-patterna-and-patternb

Answer (score 29):

Here's how `unapply` works in general:

When you do

```
obj match {case Pattern(foo, bar) => ... }
```

`Pattern.unapply(obj)` is called. This can either return `None` in which case the pattern match is a failure, or `Some(x,y)` in which case `foo` and `bar` are bound to `x` and `y`.

If instead of `Pattern(foo, bar)` you did `Pattern(OtherPattern, YetAnotherPatter)` then `x` would be matched against the pattern `OtherPattern` and `y` would be matched against `YetAnotherPattern`. If all of those pattern matches are successful, the body of the match executes, otherwise the next pattern is tried.

when the name of a pattern is not alphanumeric, but a symbol (like `&`), it is used infix, i.e. you write `foo & bar` instead of `&(foo, bar)`.

---

So here `&` is a pattern that always returns `Some(a,a)` no matter what `a` is. So `&` always matches and binds the matched object to its two operands. In code that means that

```
obj match {case x & y => ...}
```

will always match and both `x` and `y` will have the same value as `obj`.

In the example above this is used to apply two different patterns to the same object.

I.e. when you do

```
obj match { case SomePattern & SomeOtherPattern => ...}`
```

first the pattern `&` is applied. As I said, it always matches and binds `obj` to its LHS and its RHS. So then `SomePattern` is applied to `&`'s LHS (which is the same as `obj`) and `SomeOtherPattern` is applied to `&`'s RHS (which is also the same as `obj`).

So in effect, you just applied two patterns to the same object.

Comment: I can see that's how & is intended, but not how the definition of & delivers that. Can you explain further?

Comment: @Paul: I thought, I did. The `&` pattern takes one object and returns it twice. That's all it does. I'll try to explain a bit further, but that's basically all there is to it.

Comment: Yes, it's probably me being dense (and a Scala neophyte). If you have pointers to stuff I should have read first, please post 'em!

Answer (score 7):

Let's do this from the code. First, a small rewrite:

```
object & { def unapply[A](a: A) = Some(a, a) }

"Julie" match {
  // case Brothers(_) & Sisters(_) => "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)"
  case &(Brothers(_), Sisters(_)) => "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)"
  case Siblings(_) => "Julie's siblings are all the same sex"
  case _ => "Julie has no siblings"
}
```

The new rewrite means *exactly the same thing*. The comment line is using infix notation for extractors, and the second is using normal notation. They both translate to the same thing.

So, Scala will feed "Julie" to the extractor, repeatedly, until all unbound variables got assigned to `Some` thing. The first extractor is `&`, so we get this:

```
&.unapply("Julie") == Some(("Julie", "Julie"))
```

We got `Some` back, so we can proceed with the match. Now we have a tuple of two elements, and we have two extractors inside `&` as well, so we feed each element of the tuple to each extractor:

```
Brothers.unapply("Julie") == ?
Sisters.unapply("Julie") == ?
```

If both of these return `Some` thing, then the match is succesful. Just for fun, let's rewrite this code without pattern matching:

```
val pattern = "Julie"
val extractor1 = &.unapply(pattern)
if (extractor1.nonEmpty && extractor1.get.isInstanceOf[Tuple2]) {
  val extractor11 = Brothers.unapply(extractor1.get._1)
  val extractor12 = Sisters.unapply(extractor1.get._2)
  if (extractor11.nonEmpty && extractor12.nonEmpty) {
    "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)"
  } else {
    "Test Siblings and default case, but I'll skip it here to avoid repetition" 
  }
} else {
  val extractor2 = Siblings.unapply(pattern)
  if (extractor2.nonEmpty) {
    "Julie's siblings are all the same sex"
  } else {
    "Julie has no siblings"
}
```

Ugly looking code, even without optimizing to only get `extractor12` if `extractor11` isn't empty, and without the code repetition that should have gone where there's a comment. So I'll write it in yet another style:

```
val pattern = "Julie"
& unapply pattern  filter (_.isInstanceOf[Tuple2]) flatMap { pattern1 =>
  Brothers unapply pattern1._1 flatMap { _ =>
    Sisters unapply pattern1._2 flatMap { _ =>
      "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)"
    }
  }
} getOrElse {
  Siblings unapply pattern map { _ =>
    "Julie's siblings are all the same sex"
  } getOrElse {
    "Julie has no siblings"
  }
}
```

The pattern of `flatMap`/`map` at the beginning suggests yet another way of writing this:

```
val pattern = "Julie"
(
  for {
    pattern1 <- & unapply pattern
    if pattern1.isInstanceOf[Tuple2]
    _ <- Brothers unapply pattern1._1
    _ <- Sisters unapply pattern1._2
  } yield "Julie has both brother(s) and sister(s)
) getOrElse (
 for {
   _ <- Siblings unapply pattern
 } yield "Julie's siblings are all the same sex"
) getOrElse (
  "julie has no siblings"
)
```

You should be able to run all this code and see the results for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For additional info, I recommend reading the *Infix Operation Patterns* section (8.1.10) of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf.).

> An infix operation pattern `p op q` is a
>   shorthand for the constructor or
>   extractor pattern `op(p,q)`. The
>   precedence and associativity of
>   operators in patterns is the same as
>   in expressions.

Which is pretty much all there is to it, but then you can read about constructor and extractor patterns and patterns in general. It helps separate the syntactic sugar aspect (the "magic" part of it) from the fairly simple idea of pattern matching:

> A pattern is built from constants,
>   constructors, variables and type
>   tests. Pattern matching tests whether
>   a given value (or sequence of values)
>   has the shape defined by a pattern,
>   and, if it does, binds the variables
>   in the pattern to the corresponding
>   components of the value (or sequence
>   of values).