# How to understand "case id ~ username => _" in anorm?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

Play2's anorm has a nice DSL of result parser:

```
case class User(id:Pk[String], name:String)

object User {
  val parser = get[String]("id") ~ get[String]("name") map { 
    case id ~ name => User(id,name) 
  }
}
```

I don't understand this part `case id ~ name`, why there can be a `~` between two variables?

I see `case` normally as:

```
case id => _
case (a,b) => _
case Array(a, _*) => _
```

But I don't see `case id ~ name`.

The source of `~` is here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/SqlParser.scala#L49

It defines a case class `~`:

```
case class ~[+A, +B](_1:A, _2:B)
```

And I write a simple test:

```
case class ~[+A, +B](_1:A, _2:B)

new ~("a","b") match {
    case x ~ y => println(x , y)
}
```

It prints `a,b`, but why the syntax is `case x ~ y`?

Comment: This is infix notation. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008271/explain-this-pattern-matching-code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're already halfway there. It is possible because Scala lets you do that for all types that have been declared with **two** type parameters.

For example:

```
scala> case class Foo[X,Y]()
defined class Foo

scala> val x: Int Foo Double = Foo[Int,Double]()
x: Foo[Int,Double] = Foo()
```

While it may seem odd at first, it's actually a really nice property as this syntax can make things more readable. Consider the following example where a custom type for a tuple is defined:

```
class |::|[A, B](val left: A, val right: B)

object |::| {
  def unapply[A, B](o: A |::| B) = Some((o.left, o.right))
}
```

Here, `A |::| B` is used as infix notation for `|::|[A, B]`. On the other hand, scala *also* allows infix notation for pattern matching (thanks to incrop for the reminder), as in case of the constructor in the following example:

```
new |::|("Hello","World") match {
  case l |::| r => Console println (l + "," + r)
  case _ =>
}
```

Comment: The concepts of infix type constructor and infix operation pattern are different things.

Comment: @fotNelton, thank you! I understand it now. And thanks to incrop too.