# LiftWeb Rest explanation

Tags: scala, lift, implicit-conversion, implicit

http://simply.liftweb.net/index-5.4.html describes the LiftWeb REST.

What bothers me is that I can't exactly understand. 
For example,
`case "count" :: Nil JsonGet _`

I suspect that there is and implicit conventions from List to some another object, and I've found `Get` method that seems to accept List and Req type, but how it getting together? 
Please, help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain this pattern matching code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008271/explain-this-pattern-matching-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is no implicit conversion going on here at all - [`JsonGet`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/11c58258650f217f4392f445eb1617d70a3f1b69/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/rest/RestHelper.scala#L171) is an instance of [`TestGet`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/11c58258650f217f4392f445eb1617d70a3f1b69/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/rest/RestHelper.scala#L154-L165), which provides an `unapply` method that returns an `Option[(List[String], Req)]`.  Scala allows [calling unapply as an infix method](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns), so that construct is sugar for:

```
case JsonGet("cout" :: Nil, _) => // the second argument is the Req instance
```

Comment: thanks. 
My question doubles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008271/explain-this-pattern-matching-code

And here is some explanation on the requirement of such extractors
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html