# Matching on class members "error: not found: value &&"

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get going in Scala from the Twitter Scala School but am stumbling over syntax errors.  When I run the Pattern Matching code from the "Basics continued" tutorial http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics2.html#match through my sbt console the compiler turns me back with "error: not found: value &&".  Has something changed in Scala to take what probably worked when the tutorial was written but doesn't work now?  The classes involved are

```
class Calculator(pBrand: String, pModel: String) {
  /**
   * A constructor
   */
  val brand: String = pBrand
  val model: String = pModel
  val color: String = if (brand.toUpperCase == "TI") {
    "blue"
  } else if (brand.toUpperCase == "HP") {
    "black"
  } else {
    "white"
  }

  // An instance method
  def add(m: Int, n: Int): Int = m + n
}

class ScientificCalculator(pBrand: String, pModel: String) extends Calculator(pBrand: String, pModel: String) {
  def log(m: Double, base: Double) = math.log(m) / math.log(base)
}

class EvenMoreScientificCalculator(pBrand: String, pModel: String) extends ScientificCalculator(pBrand: String, pModel: String) {
  def log(m: Int): Double = log(m, math.exp(1))
}
```

My repl looks something like this...

```
bobk-mbp:Scala_School bobk$ sbt console
[info] Set current project to default-b805b6 (in build file:/Users/bobk/work/_workspace/Scala_School/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
...
scala> def calcType(calc: Calculator) = calc match {
     |   case calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "20B" => "financial"
     |   case calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "48G" => "scientific"
     |   case calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "30B" => "business"
     |   case _ => "unknown"
     | }
<console>:9: error: not found: value &&
         case calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "20B" => "financial"
                                 ^
<console>:10: error: not found: value &&
         case calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "48G" => "scientific"
                                 ^
<console>:11: error: not found: value &&
         case calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "30B" => "business"
                                 ^
scala>
```

How to I get the use case of AND on my cases when I'm doing Matching on Class Members?

Thanks in advance.  I'm new to this.

Comment: Btw, you use an outdated version of Scala. Current version is `2.10.2`.

Comment: The results are the same when I force SBT console to use a more recent version of Scala.

Comment: Yea, of course, but an outdated version is an outdated version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're matching by value, as in your case, you can not only use guards, but stick to plain pattern matching:

```
def calcType(calc: Calculator) = (calc.brand, calc.model)  match {
     case ("hp", "20B") => "financial"
     case ("hp", "48G") => "scientific"
     case ("hp", "30B") => "business"
     case _             => "unknown"
}
```

I find this one easier to parse.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about!  Too bad I can't undo the Right answer check as I think this version captures, exactly, the spirit of the case.  What, exactly, happen here?  Your function turn the brand and model values from the Calculator into a tuple and sends that kid through the match?

Comment: Yep, what is going on here is matching against tuple. Moreover, if Calculator was a case class, you could write something like `calc match { case Calculator("hp", "20B") => "financial" .... `. *(Shameless plug -- actually you can undo)*

Comment: @BobKuhar: It is possible to undo the right answer. Just mark a different one as the right one...

Answer (score 2):

When you want to test a condition with a pattern, then you need to use a [guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266915/does-scala-have-guards):

```
calc match {
  case _ if calc.brand == "hp" && calc.model == "20B" => "financial"
  ...
}
```

With the `_` you denote that you don't bother of the concrete value `calc` has, but of some other condition mentioned in the guard.

Btw, it is possible to write a [conjunction extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261358/pattern-matching-with-conjunctions-patterna-and-patternb):

```
object && {
  def unapply[A](a: A) = Some((a, a))
}
```

But it will not work in your concrete case.

Comment: Hmmm.  So the twitter doc stuff can't work as written?  They cover "guards", very briefly, in the section preceding the one I lifted my code from.  It looks like this is a known issue:  https://github.com/twitter/scala_school/pull/89

Comment: Thats it!  But funky.  The need to "capture" the _ seems redundant to me.  Regardless.  It compiles and my understanding of "the new shiny" has improved.