# Is | (or) short circuited when pattern matching in scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I noticed that there is no || operator available when pattern matching - is | short circuited?

Comment: Official SLS says that - The alternative pattern matches a value v if at least one its alternatives matches v, so i think that would be at least logical, to be short-circuted, cause this operator is not boolean or, but a denotes a pattern alternative

Comment: See also: [Pattern matching with conjunctions (PatternA AND PatternB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261358/pattern-matching-with-conjunctions-patterna-and-patternb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In pattern matching, `|` is short circuited.  You can't call `unapply` or the like (with returned parameters) with the or-operator, where side-effects might be more likely.  So short-circuiting is purely an optimization technique (won't affect the correctness of the code except in extraordinary cases such as a side-effecting equals method).  This does mean you are limited in your ability to short circuit or not for performance or side-effecting reasons.

To see this, if we write this code:

```
def matchor(s: String) = s match {
  case "tickle" | "fickle" => "sickle"
  case _ => "hammer"
}
```

We see this bytecode (in part)

```
public java.lang.String matchor(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_1
   1:   astore_2
   2:   ldc #12; //String tickle
   4:   aload_2
   5:   astore_3
   6:   dup
   7:   ifnonnull   18
   10:  pop
   11:  aload_3
   12:  ifnull  25
   15:  goto    31
   18:  aload_3
   19:  invokevirtual   #16; //Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
   22:  ifeq    31
   25:  iconst_1
   26:  istore  4
   28:  goto    66
   31:  ldc #18; //String fickle
   33:  aload_2
   ...
   66:  iload   4
   68:  ifeq    78
   71:  ldc #20; //String sickle
   73:  astore  6
   75:  goto    82
   ...
   82:  aload   6
   84:  areturn
```

See the jump on line 28 to avoid testing the `"fickle"` case?  That's the short-circuit.

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks for actually pulling out the bytecode!

Comment: That's a great answer indeed

Comment: Talk about going above and beyond!

Comment: It's really easy to get bytecode, by the way.  This is not some kind of heroics!  `javap -c -private MyClassName` on the command-line will do it.

Answer (score 3):

`|` short-circuits.

```
object First {
    def unapply(str: String): Boolean = {
        println("in First")
        str == "first"
    }
}

object Second {
    def unapply(str: String) = {
        println("in Second")
        str == "second"
    }
}

object Run extends App {
    "first" match {
        case First() | Second() => None
    }

    //Output: In First

    "first" match {
        case Second() | First() => None
    }

    //Output: In Second\nIn First
}
```